# How do I convert Doctrine resultset into an array?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I am getting a resultset using the following:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
  $test = $em->getRepository('RestWebServiceBundle:Test')->findall();
```

How do I convert $test to an array?

toArray does not seem to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe there is a Hydration mode that will generate Arrays instead of objects:

So'd you use: `Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY` assuming the findall method has not been overridden.

```
$test = $em->getRepository('RestWebServiceBundle:Test')->findall(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

If it is overridden, you can use it as a parameter on your `getResult` call.

Example from Doctrine2 manual:

```
$users = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

See Here:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#array-hydration

Comment: @MarinSagovac Thanks. Link fixed.